# Get SIP Invite Header on Watson Voice Agent

Tags: twilio, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I'm doing an application in Java that connects a phone call to Watson Voice Agent to my user via Twilio and i need to pass some information to the Voice Agent and make it available to the assistant. 
I'm passing the information on the sip invite header but I can't get the information on the assistant dialog.
My Twilio call class:

```
public String callPhone(String to, String from,String data)throws URISyntaxException{
        Twilio.init(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);

        Call call = Call.creator(
                new com.twilio.type.PhoneNumber(to),
                new com.twilio.type.PhoneNumber(from),
                new URI("https://handler.twilio.com/twiml/xxxx?data_sent="+data))
                .create();

        return call.getSid();
    }
```

My TwinML Bin code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
  <Dial>
    <Sip>sip:{{From}}@us-south.voiceagent.cloud.ibm.com?X-data={{data_sent}}</Sip>
  </Dial\>
</Response>
```

In my Voice Agent config I put the "Custom SIP INVITE header" as "data" (without quotes) and in the Assistant I try to access $vgwSIPCustomInviteHeader but the Voice Agent doesn't say anything where this value should be.

Answer (score 0):

I've already solved it, for some reason if I use the header parameter with "_" the TwinML Bin doesn't seem to be able to send the value correctly, I changed the parameter to "dataSent" and now it works fine.